# Remove the tests from an ECLEmma report

Tags: unit-testing, eclipse-plugin

I think [eclemma](http://www.eclemma.org/) is a great tool for giving a rough estimate of my tests coverage, but in the reports, it also displays the coverage of the tests itself, which is annoying.
Is there any easy way to disable this (and thus only show the program code coverage)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you keep your test cases in a separate folder, yes. When you go to run coverage again click "coverage configurations". Select the "coverage" tab and deselect the folders you don't want included.

If it won't let you deselect single folders, you need to go into the project preferences, open up the "Java Build Path" section and go to the "Source" tab. Check the box that says "allow output folders for source folders" and assign the test folder to a different output location. You should now be able to deselect individual folders when running coverage.

Comment: Isn't there some way to disable individual files (e.g. with a regex) ?

Comment: @billybob It doesn't seem to be supported in the Eclipse plugin (EclEmma) but you can run EMMA from the commandline and or ant with filters: http://emma.sourceforge.net/reference/ch02s06s02.html